# How can create a new DataFrame from a list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

Hello guys i have this function that gets the row Values from a DataFrame, converts them into a list and the makes a Dataframe from it.

```
//Gets the row content from the "content column"
 val dfList  = df.select("content").rdd.map(r => r(0).toString).collect.toList

    val dataSet = sparkSession.createDataset(dfList)

   //Makes a new DataFrame
    sparkSession.read.json(dataSet)
```

What i need to do to make a list with other column values so i can have another DataFrame with the other columns values

```
val dfList  = df.select("content","collection", "h").rdd.map(r => {
      println("******ROW********")
      println(r(0).toString)
      println(r(1).toString)
      println(r(2).toString) //These have the row values from the other 
                             //columns in the select
    }).collect.toList
```

thanks

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here ?  if you have few columns to select you can directly select to get a new dataframe with selected columns why we need to collect and make a list and again make another dataframe? for me seems like you are complicaating things to the core....

Comment: i'm trying to make a new DataFrame from the "content" column wich is a json like this:
´´´´´
{"_id":"5ccb24112584a9041e75dd38","currency":"MXN","exchange_rate":1.0,"fraud_status":"in_review","status":"pending_payment"}
´´´´´
so each of the json field is a column. I already achieved that, but i need to attach the other columns to this new DataFrame

Comment: can you post json here

Answer (score 1):

Approach doesn't look right, you don't need to collect dataframe to just add new columns. Try adding columns to directly to dataframe using withColumn() withColumnRenamed() https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/1.6/sparkr/functions/withColumn.html.

If you want to bring columns from another dataframe try joining. In any case it's not good idea to use collect as it will bring all your data to driver.